# In PyTorch calc Euclidean distance instead of matrix multiplication

Tags: python, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

Let say we have 2 matrices:

```
mat = torch.randn([20, 7]) * 100
mat2 = torch.randn([7, 20]) * 100

n, m = mat.shape
```

The simplest usual matrix multiplication looks like this:

```
def mat_vec_dot_product(mat, vect):
    n, m = mat.shape
    
    res = torch.zeros([n])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            res[i] += mat[i][j] * vect[j]
        
    return res

res = torch.zeros([n, n])
for k in range(n):
    res[:, k] = mat_vec_dot_product(mat, mat2[:, k])
```

But what if I need to apply L2 norm instead of dot product? The code is next:

```
def mat_vec_l2_mult(mat, vect):
    n, m = mat.shape
    
    res = torch.zeros([n])
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            res[i] += (mat[i][j] - vect[j]) ** 2
            
    res = res.sqrt()
        
    return res

for k in range(n):
    res[:, k] = mat_vec_l2_mult(mat, mat2[:, k])
```

Can we do this somehow in an optimal way using Torch or any other libraries? Cause naive O(n^3) Python code works really slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`torch.cdist`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cdist.html#torch-cdist) for L2 norm - euclidean distance

```
res = torch.cdist(mat, mat2.permute(1,0), p=2)
```

Here, I have used `permute` to swap dim of `mat2` from `7,20` to `20,7`

Answer (score 2):

First of all, matrix multiplication in PyTorch has a built-in operator: `@`.
So, to multiply mat and mat2 you simply do:

```
mat @ mat2
```

(should work, assuming dimensions agree).

Now, to compute the Sum of Squared Differences(SSD, or L2-norm of differences) which you seem to compute in your second block, you can do a simple trick.
Since the squared L2-norm `||m_i - v||^2` (where `m_i` is the i'th row of matrix `M` and `v` is the vector) is equal to the dot product `<m_i - v, m_i-v>` - from linearity of the dot product you obtain: `<m_i,m_i> - 2<m_i,v> + <v,v>` so you can compute the SSD of each row in `M` from vector `v` by computing once the squared L2-norm of each row, once the dot product between each row and the vector and once the L2-norm of the vector. This can be done in `O(n^2)`.
However, for the SSD between 2 matrices you will still get `O(n^3)`. Improvements can be made though by vectorizing the operations instead of using loops.
Here is a simple implementation for 2 matrices:

```
def mat_mat_l2_mult(mat,mat2):
    rows_norm = (torch.norm(mat, dim=1, p=2, keepdim=True)**2).repeat(1,mat2.shape[1])
    cols_norm = (torch.norm(mat2, dim=0, p=2, keepdim=True)**2).repeat(mat.shape[0], 1)
    rows_cols_dot_product = mat @ mat2
    ssd = rows_norm -2*rows_cols_dot_product + cols_norm
    return ssd.sqrt()

mat = torch.randn([20, 7])
mat2 = torch.randn([7,20])
print(mat_mat_l2_mult(mat, mat2))
```

The resulting matrix will have at each cell `i,j` the L2-norm of the difference between each row `i` in `mat` and each column `j` in `mat2`.